# MIME type issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mime-types, src

I am working in a Web site. My `<head>` is like below.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js/blob/master/build/panolens.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        const panorama = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama('./images/project.jpg');
        const viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer();
        viewer.add(panorama);
    </script>
</head>
```

But I am getting error `The resource from “https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js/blob/master/build/panolens.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).`

[image]

Why I am seeing this error ?

Comment: Because github does not want you linking to the files.... It is set to a different content type.

Answer (score 2):

1. use rawgit.com instead of github.com

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/dev/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="https://rawgit.com/pchen66/panolens.js/master/build/panolens.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        const panorama = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama('./images/project.jpg');
        const viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer();
        viewer.add(panorama);
    </script>
</head>
```